# Linq query to get child records

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have

```
string inputXml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
                <Parent>
                  <Child>
                      <Child1 value='10' />  
                      <Child2 value= '20' />                           
                   </Child>
                   <Child>
                      <Child1 value='30' />  
                      <Child2 value='40' /> 
                      <Child3 value='50' />                          
                   </Child>                
                </Parent>";
```

Need a linq query that will fetch all teh values from the inner childs.

Output will be

```
Child1 : 10
Child2: 20
Child1: 30
Child2 : 40
Child3: 50
```

I am lost after this

```
XDocument source = null;
source = XDocument.Parse(inputXml);


var res = (from data in source.Descendants("Child")
          select data);
```

Help needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var res = xmlSkuDescDoc.Descendants("Child")
                       .SelectMany(c => c.Elements())
                       .Select(c => new { Name = c.Name, Value = (string)c.Attribute("value")});
```

This should return list of anonymous objects with two properties: `Name` and `Value`

Comment: I am unclear why this was marked as the answer when the OP clearly stated he wanted Query syntax...